# How to prevent swf to redirect parent html?

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I am showing lots of ads (swf as well as images) on my page. But I have a issue that some of the swf are having some redirection link on it. So when ever anyone clicks on it, page redirected to 3rd party url or some thing like this : /undefined. I want to prevent this kind of behaviour. This is the code which I am using to display swf

```
<embed pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" menu="false" wmode="opaque" quality="high" play="true" allowscriptaccess="never" allowNetworkAccess="never" style="width:500px;height:500px;" src="/name_of_swf.swf" >
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the way to do so...

Use below object declaration:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/
cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" width="360" height="240">
```

And use below param in embed code :

```
allowNetworking="none"
```

Hope this may help to others also....